# low-latency charting?

Tags: libraries, charts, latency

Need to deliver real-time charts (mostly bar and line charts) and wondering if a fast library can help.

I guess that C is mandatory for speed and I would favor frame-buffer drawing (rather than a specific drawing package) for portability.

Environment will be *nix AND Windows. That's for a Web application.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be more precise to get a good answer. Environment? Application? Programming language? Web? Desktop?

Comment: I think you're optimizing in the wrong place. If this is a web app, your speed limitation is probably the browser and network, so the graph generator doesn't need to be optimized and written in C. Unless it is doing heavy processing to generate the graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will suit you but [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) has APIs for charting data in various ways.
These are two related site references:
- NetTuts+ [Easy Graphs with Google Chart Tools](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-graphs-with-google-chart-tools/)
- [jQuery Google Charts 1.0](http://maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/)

Comment: Alas, if they're considering C, the additional latency from the request alone may be a dealbreaker.